# How to arrange widgets in Stack

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, stack

When expanding the `DropdownButton` widget, when I want to scroll the dropdown list up or down, then my map in the background is scaled, and the dropdown list and the container with the `Авторизация` button have a transparency through which I can interact with the map (move, scale). Is it all about the Stack Widget? How to solve this problem?

Dropdown list

[image: dropdown list]

dropdown list when you scroll down (map scale changes)

[image: dropdown list when you scroll down (map scale changes)]

**`map_widget.dart`**

```
return Stack(
      children: [
        _getMapWidget(),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: StreamBuilder<MapState>(
            initialData: _store.getInitialState(),
            stream: _store.getStateStream(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              final state = snapshot.data!;
              if (state is MapStateLoading) {
                return _Loading();
              } else if (state is MapStateContent) {
                return SizedBox.shrink();
              } else if (state is MapStateError) {
                return _Error();
              } else {
                throw Exception('Unhandled state type :$state');
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: _cultureSelectionAlignment,
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(12),
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 0, 12, 0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: UiKitColors.white),
            child: _cultureWidgetFactory.create(
              (culture) => _store.process(
                MapActionCultureClick(culture),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

**`guest_widget.dart`**

```
Widget _Body(BuildContext context) => Stack(
        children: [
          _mapWidgetBuilder(context),
          _SignIn(context),
        ],
      );

  Widget _SignIn(BuildContext context) => SafeArea(
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          child: Container(
            height: _signInContainerHeight,
            width: _signInContainerWidth,
            decoration: _SignInBackground(),
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
                    child: Text(
                      _stringProvider.guestAuthorizationMessage,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                  _AuthButton(context),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
```

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `IgnorePointer` widget,

Wrap your map widget with this widget and it has flag called `ignoring`. when you interacting with dropdownButton just make it `true`.

Comment: How can i make it `true` on `DropdownButton` ?